# Check if string contains at least one part of an enum

Tags: c#, enums

Is there an easy way to check if a longer string contains one of the defined parts of an enum using C#

For example I've got the following enum:

```
enum myEnum
{
   this,
   is,
   an,
   enum
};
```

and I have such a string:

```
string myString = "here I have a sample string containing an enum";
```

since the string is containing the keyword `enum` I'd like to find this within the string.

so I would need a function like `string.contains(myString,myEnum)`. This function should then ruturn true or false.
Of course I could compare each value in the enum - but there might be an easier way...

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

your emum...

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    @this,
    @is,
    an,
    @enum
}
```

... to check ...

```
var myString = "here I have a sample string containing an enum";
var found = Enum.GetNames(typeof(MyEnum)).Any(e=>myString.Contains(e));
```

Comment: @ChrsitophH Our answers are the same, Matthew just beat me by 15 seconds.

Comment: To be fair yours also makes a list instead of just using the array from `Enum.GetNames` ;)

Answer (score 2):

First, get all the string values of your enum

```
List<string> s = new List<string>(Enum.GetNames(typeof(myEnum)));
```

Then, check for existence!

```
s.Any(s=> myString.Contains(s));
```